# Java print arraylist numbered

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

i have this

```
public String toString()
{
        return "a " + year + " " +  make + " " + model +
                " with a VIN# of " + vin + " and a mileage of " + miles;
}
```

and this:

```
ArrayList<Auto> autos = new ArrayList<Auto>();
```

and this:

```
 public static void loadNewData(ArrayList<Auto> a, ArrayList<Customer> c)
    {
        a.add(new Auto(2009,"Ford" , "Mustang","ABC123", 1256.54));
        a.add(new Auto(2010,"Chevy","Camero","QWI459", 33.98));
        a.add(new Auto(1970,"Pink","Cadillac","950AKH", 212874.51));
        a.add(new Auto(2007,"Lotus","Elise MkII","1A2D3F", 12859.90));

        c.add(new Customer( "Brett Farve",false));
        c.add(new Customer( "Bruce Springsteen",true));
        c.add(new Customer( "Mickey Mouse", true));
        c.add(new Customer( "Peyton Manning", true));
        c.add(new Customer( "Donald Duck", true));
    }
```

i then join all that and print:

```
System.out.println(autos.toString());
```

but it comes out like this:

```
[a 2009 Ford Mustang with a VIN# of ABC123 and a mileage of 1256.54, a 2010 Chevy Camero with a VIN# of QWI459 and a mileage of 33.98, a 1970 Pink Cadillac with a VIN# of 950AKH and a mileage of 212874.51, a 2007 Lotus Elise MkII with a VIN# of 1A2D3F and a mileage of 12859.9]
```

how can i make the print to come out like this:

> 1. a 2009 Ford Mustang with a VIN# of ABC123 and a mileage of 1256.54
> 2. a 2010 Chevy Camero with a VIN# of QWI459 and a mileage of 33.98
> 3. a 1970 Pink Cadillac with a VIN# of 950AKH and a mileage of 212874.51
> 4. a 2007 Lotus Elise MkII with a VIN# of 1A2D3F and a mileage of 12859.9

Comment: well obviously by not doing `System.out.println(autos.toString());`  Do you not know how to A)`System.out.print("1. ");`   and B)do you not know how to println the contents of the first element? You should really break the problem down in your head and ask how to print the contents of the first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over your list and do a `System.out.println` for each entry. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < autos.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + autos.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `\r \n` to your return statement:

```
public String toString()
{
        return "a " + year + " " +  make + " " + model +
                " with a VIN# of " + vin + " and a mileage of " + miles + "\r \n";
}
```